# How to prove the following inequality using Lagrangian multipliers?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, lagrange-multiplier

Find the maximum and minimum values of the function $f(x,y,z)=(xyz)^2$ where $(x,y,z)$ is on the sphere $x^2+y^2+z^2=r^2$.

Then show using above that $(abc)^{1/3} \leq (a+b+c)/3$. For non-negative $a,b,c$

For the first part I have set up the Lagrangian and calculated the partial derivatives.

That is we have $$2xy^2z^2+2\lambda x =0\\2x^2yz^2+2\lambda y =0\\2x^2y^2z+2\lambda z =0\\x^2+y^2+z^2-r^2=0$$

Now since the point lie on the sphere we have $x,y,z \neq0$ hence $\lambda=-y^2z^2=-x^2z^2=-x^2y^2 \implies x^2=y^2=z^2$ (I think).

So we get $3x^2=r^2 \implies x^2=r^2/3$ and then the maximum and minimum are the same and we have $f(x,y,z)=(xyz)^2=r^6/27$.

Okay so firstly I want to ask am I correct up until here?

And secondly how do I prove the last inequality?

Comment: If the maximum and the minimum are the same, then the function is constant on the sphere. So there must be something wrong.

Comment: Can you see where?

Comment: I'll post an answer

Comment: There are points in the sphere where $x=0$ or $y=0$ or $z=0$. Of course not the three equalities at the same time.

Comment: From the equations, either you get $x=0$ or $y=0$ or $z=0$, in which case $f=0$ (that is the minimum value). If $x,y,z\neq 0$, then you get $x^2=y^2=z^2$ and $f(x,y,z)=r^6/27$, which is the maximum value. No idea how to prove the inequality from that.

Comment: Yeah that is what I got pretty much. (I forgot to include the case $x,y,z=0$ and hence the minimum could be $0$).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have that $f(x,y,z) \ge 0$ for all $(x,y,z)$. Now $f(0,r/{\sqrt 2}, r/{\sqrt 2}) = 0$, hence the minimum of $f$ is $0$.

I am not sure what you mean by $x,y,z \neq 0$, but if it is "$ x \neq 0$ and $y \neq 0$ and $z \neq 0$", then it is incorrect. What we know is that at least one of them should be $\neq 0$, but this is not important.

From the system you have, multiply the first equation by $x$, the second by $y$ and the third by $z$ and subtract the equations from each other to get $x^2 = y^2 = z^2$ (realizing that $\lambda = 0$ corresponds to $f(x,y,z) = 0$, and then that we may suppose $\lambda \neq 0$). Then, $x^2 = y^2 = z^2 = r^2/3$. Hence, $f$ achieves its maximum $6$ times (at the points $(\pm r/{\sqrt 3}, \pm r/{\sqrt 3},\pm r/{\sqrt 3})$), and this maximum is $f(r/{\sqrt 3},r/{\sqrt 3},r/{\sqrt 3}) = r^6/27$.

See Wore's comment for how to get the inequality.

Comment: @Wore you are right. I'll fix that.

Comment: You can fix it like this: since $a,b,c\geq 0$, there are $x,y,z$ such that $a=x^2,b=y^2,c=z^2$. Choose now $r$ such that $r^2=a+b+c=x^2+y^2+z^2$. Using what we know we obtain $f(x,y,z)=abc\leq r^6/27=(a+b+c)^3/27$. Finally, take cubic root in both sides.

Comment: I don't think I solved the problem with my edit, but I'll think about how to do it properly

Comment: You can use the information in my previous comment if you want.

Comment: @Wore I like what you did, but I'll stick with my solution because I am too lazy to write that out again, but I'll edit to refer the OP to your comment.

Comment: Fair enough, but it seems that you are morally obligated to find a flawless correction of your original answer since it has been already accepted. :)

Comment: Thank you both for your help it is a shame I can only award best answer and that is it. Wore you were a help also :)

Comment: You're welcome. @Wore I am interested in being correct, not in having my answer accepted. After some thought, I realized that the inequality I used is not true. In fact, it is the opposite inequality that holds (also, in general, $\left( \frac{a+b+c}3 \right)^p \le \frac{a^p + b^p + c^p}3$ for all $p\ge 1$).

Comment: @Ahmed it was a joke! I believe that as far as the question is answered (either in some answer, or in the comments, or a combination of both) and the OP understands the solution is ok, right?